# Convert data from text format to time format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there a way to convert the following "text" data into a "time" data?

Here is a picture of the data:
[image: Talk Time]

I need to extract the numbers from the data for thousands of records at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is uniform use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)+TIME(MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,13,2))
```

Then format the cell:

```
[hh]:mm:ss
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott for your answer.

I happened to figure out another way to also do it using flash fill.

I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with the following steps:

1. Format the data as a table
2. Insert column
3. Fill the first two lines with the data in 00:00:00 format
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to flash fill the rest of the column